# Maven tool for eclipse

Tags: maven-plugin, eclipse-kepler

After installing maven (m2e) plugin for eclipse kepler I am not able to view maven in the menu (run as).
How can I get Maven visible in the "run as" menu?

Answer (score 0):

If the project is already in Eclipse, right-click on the project and (if I recall) select Configure -> enable Maven nature.  If it's not in Eclipse, then File -> Import -> Maven -> Import Existing Maven Projects.